# Is it possible to open firefox browser from robot framework using selenium webdriver on linux in non GUI mode

Tags: linux, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I want to open firefox browser on linux using selenium webdriver in non GUI mode. 
Note i don't have a internet connection on server.

I tried this command to open firefox

```
firefox &
```

and get this error

```
Error: no display specified
```

Comment: Yes, you'll need to set `DISPLAY` variable. Check this link -
 https://superuser.com/questions/325630/how-can-i-export-display-from-a-linux-terminal-to-a-windows-pc

Comment: Try using /path/to/firefox -headless If I am correct headless mode of firefox don't need any virtual frame buffer